# Facebook Like button with thumb up icon?

Tags: facebook, layout, facebook-like

As you already know from this link http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ you may create Facebook Like button. But...

When I choose 'layout style' to something else than 'standard', little 'thumb up' icon inside button is changed to Facebook logo.

Is there a way to have 'layout style' set to 'box_count' and to little 'thumb up' icon ***remain*** inside button?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there isn't.  What you see is what you get for those social plugins Facebook has designed.

However, you can log a bug (and have it marked as a wishlist item) about this at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs.